# How to work with UTF-16 in python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, utf-16, python-unicode, wchar-t

I have a foreign C library which uses utf-16 in API: as function arguments, return values and structure members.

On Windows its OK with ctypes.c_wchar_p, but under OSX ctypes uses UCS-32 in c_wchar and I could not find the way to support utf-16.

Here is my research:

1. Use _SimpleCData subclassing to [redefine _check_retval_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438036/736762).

   - it allows a transparent conversion of utf-16 to Python string.
   - can be placed as C structure member
   - But it doesn't allow to handle strings as arguments, its `from_param()` method never been called (**Why?**):
     `func('str', b'W\x00B\x00\x00\x00')  # passed without conversion`
2. Use own type with `from_param()` method.

   - advantages: can be initialized either with constructor or encoded on the fly when passing strings to function:
   - disadvantages: cannot be used as function return type or structure member.

Here it is:

```
ustr = myutf16('hello')
func(ustr)
func('hello')   # calls myutf16.from_param('hello')
```

Comment: Does it have to be with "ctypes" rather than, say, "unicode" and "codecs"?

Comment: It is very desirable. Of course, I can manually encode and decode utf-16, but then I need to create a lot of wrappers for each function call.

Comment: I think from a safety/understandabilty perspective, using only "unicode" objects or "UTF-8" strings internally and performing conversions only where calling out to other systems and libraries will be a lot better in the long-run compared to other approaches. I would not pass around other kinds of strings in the system except where the encoding/decoding overhead makes it strictly necessary to do otherwise. Mixing lots of different string types can make the code very challenging.

Comment: If you're using Python 2 only, then you can call `ctypes.set_conversion_mode('utf-16le', 'strict')`, which lets you pass `unicode` strings by converting to a temporary UTF-16 buffer. Similarly it lets you assign `unicode` to a `c_char_p` struct field. But I don't recommend this approach since it's not mirrored by the getfunc behavior, which will still be a null-terminated `char *`, plus it doesn't apply to Python 3.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for descriptor's mention,, it sound interesting for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `from_param` in a `c_char_p` subclass to encode a `unicode` string as UTF-16. You can add a `_check_retval_` method to decode a UTF-16 result as a `unicode` string. For struct fields you can use a descriptor class that handles setting and getting the attribute. Make the field a private `_name` of type `c_char_p`, and set the descriptor as the public `name`. For example:

```
import sys
import ctypes

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    unicode = str

def decode_utf16_from_address(address, byteorder='little',
                              c_char=ctypes.c_char):
    if not address:
        return None
    if byteorder not in ('little', 'big'):
        raise ValueError("byteorder must be either 'little' or 'big'")
    chars = []
    while True:
        c1 = c_char.from_address(address).value
        c2 = c_char.from_address(address + 1).value
        if c1 == b'\x00' and c2 == b'\x00':
            break
        chars += [c1, c2]
        address += 2
    if byteorder == 'little':
        return b''.join(chars).decode('utf-16le')
    return b''.join(chars).decode('utf-16be')

class c_utf16le_p(ctypes.c_char_p):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(c_utf16le_p, self).__init__()
        if value is not None:
            self.value = value

    @property
    def value(self,
              c_void_p=ctypes.c_void_p):
        addr = c_void_p.from_buffer(self).value
        return decode_utf16_from_address(addr, 'little')

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value,
              c_char_p=ctypes.c_char_p):
        value = value.encode('utf-16le') + b'\x00'
        c_char_p.value.__set__(self, value)

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = obj.encode('utf-16le') + b'\x00'
        return super(c_utf16le_p, cls).from_param(obj)

    @classmethod
    def _check_retval_(cls, result):
        return result.value

class UTF16LEField(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, cls,
                c_void_p=ctypes.c_void_p,
                addressof=ctypes.addressof):
        field_addr = addressof(obj) + getattr(cls, self.name).offset
        addr = c_void_p.from_address(field_addr).value
        return decode_utf16_from_address(addr, 'little')

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        value = value.encode('utf-16le') + b'\x00'
        setattr(obj, self.name, value)
```

**Example:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Test(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = (('x', ctypes.c_int),
                    ('y', ctypes.c_void_p),
                    ('_string', ctypes.c_char_p))
        string = UTF16LEField('_string')

    print('test 1: structure field')
    t = Test()
    t.string = u'eggs and spam'
    print(t.string)

    print('test 2: parameter and result')
    result = None

    @ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(c_utf16le_p, c_utf16le_p)
    def testfun(string):
        global result
        print('parameter: %s' % string.value)
        # callbacks leak memory except for simple return
        # values such as an integer address, so return the
        # address of a global variable.
        result = c_utf16le_p(string.value + u' and eggs')
        return ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(result).value

    print('result: %s' % testfun(u'spam'))
```

**Output:**

```
test 1: structure field
eggs and spam

test 2: parameter and result
parameter: spam
result: spam and eggs
```

Comment: It is great! The only question, can I access "str" methods from c_utf16le_p directly without ".value"?

Comment: You can add methods to `c_utf16le_p` that call `unicode` (3.x `str`) methods on `self.value` and add a `__unicode__` (3.x `__str__`) special method for printing, etc. You need to account for the value being `None` when it's a `NULL` pointer. But as a function result it's already returning the `unicode` string, so I don't know how useful it would be to add these methods.